# socket io js delay disconnect emit

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

socket.on('disconnect') is fired immediately on client side, but server side it will take one minute.

scenario 1:- if client is disconnect due to internet problem, server side disconnect emits after 1 minutes, any way to find immediately on server side.

i tried to change the pingTimeout= 30000 and pingInterval=12000 but every 30 seconds it reconnecting and connect.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a timeout delay and the socket disconnection event to make it easier to disconnect and reconnect.

When your socket connects, add them to a bucket object.

```
if (socket.request.sessionID && !bucket[socket.request.sessionID]) {
    bucket[socket.request.session.player.id] = socket.id; //nuuu they stealin mah bukkit
}
```

This adds the player's id (which I track through node session tethered into the socket) as a key to the socketId

```
//object for delayed log out
let disconnection = {
    sid : null, //socket id
    delay : null //timeout id
};
```

Create an object that stores your socket ID so you can track who was disconnected.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    disconnection.sid = socket.request.sessionID; //grab session id
    disconnection.delay = setTimeout(() => {
        //set timeout to variable, in case of reconnection
        delete bucket[socket.request.sessionID];
        //emit the disconnection event
    }, 60000);
});
```

When the user disconnects, set a timeout for however long they have to reconnect.

Upon reconnection, simply do:

```
io.sockets.on("connection", socket => {
    //check for disconnection, compare socket ids, and remove timeout if sockets match
    if (disconnection.delay && disconnection.sid == socket.request.sessionID) {
        clearTimeout(disconnection.delay);
        disconnection.sid = null;
    }
});
```

This will check the reconnection for an existing socketID and clear the timeout, successfully establishing the connection once more.

Note that this code is a copy of [SourceUndead](https://github.com/RUJodan/SourceUndead/blob/master/server.js) (my game) so some of it might not directly translate to you (for instance, my socket variable is bound with the session as well), but the concept of a timeout disconnection is the same.

Comment: I assume you have `bucket.push()` to store socketIDs (clientIDs) for every time a user connects as well?  It may be helpful to add that tidbit to help our friend avoid confusion...

Comment: Sort of yes, bucket is an object so not pushing. I'll add in the snippet.